# Adding quote to a json file that does not have quote

Tags: javascript, docker

Inside docker container, I am writing out to a file and need access to that file. However, it does not cannot be parsed and access because it lack the double quote in the key value. What  should i do so then when i do `SampleFile['KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO']` it would output tcp. how should i go about adding " " to all the key in file/output.json.

```
const myConsole = new console.Console(fs.createWriteStream('./file/output.json'));
    myConsole.log(process.env);

  KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO: 'tcp',
  npm_config_fetch_retry_mintimeout: '10000',
  npm_config_maxsockets: '50',
  npm_config_offline: '',
  npm_config_sso_poll_frequency: '500',
  npm_config_umask: '0022',
```

Comment: what does console.log(process.env) do vs JSON.stringify(process.env)

Comment: `console.log` creates a human-readable representation of the object, not JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `console.log()` if you're trying to create a JSON file. Use `JSON.stringify()` and `write()`.

```
const jsonFile = fs.createWriteStream('./file/output.json');
jsonFile.write(JSON.stringify(process.env)).then(() => jsonFile.close());
```

Comment: this when when i deploy using this way, there are no pod events, and the values still cannot be accessed.

Comment: when i cat file/output.json, there is a file created { KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO: 'tcp',
  npm_config_fetch_retry_mintimeout: '10000',
  npm_config_maxsockets: '50',
  npm_config_offline: '',
  npm_config_sso_poll_frequency: '500',
  npm_config_umask: '0022', }. Is there a way to add quotes directly to the keys

Comment: I don't believe you. `JSON.stringify()` will always put quotes around the object keys, and it uses double quotes rather than single quotes.

Comment: I don't know anything about pod events, so I can't help you with that. This is just basic JavaScript and node.js.

Comment: I have to get all the values from the printenv into the output.json. Is that the way or is there another way?

Comment: I don't understand why this doesn't do what you want.

Comment: in that case, does it have to go through JSON.parse before using accessing the elements?

Comment: If you want to read the file from JS, yes, you use JSON.parse.